# Sorted-array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects that represent products. These products have a `ratingReviews` field, and a `price` field which can either be a string or an object. When the price is an object it has a field called `newUan` which holds the new price value.

The string that `ratingReviews` contains is a number followed by a word.

The string that `price` or `newUan` contains is a space-delineated human-readable number followed by a currency name.

I want to write two functions that, without mutating the original array:

1. Sort the products according to the number in `ratingReviews`.
2. Sort the products according to the number in `price`, or `price.newUan` if it exists.

--

I understand how to sort by `ratingReviews`:

```js
const sortedByRating = () => {
  return products.sort((a, b) => {
    return parseFloat(b.ratingReviews) - parseFloat(a.ratingReviews)
  })
}
```

and I think that sorting by `price` alone is the same. However, I don't understand how to sort by `price` *or* `price.newUan` depending on which is available. **Please show me how to do that.**

For reference, here is my dataset:

```js
const products = [
  {
    ratingReviews: '264 отзыва',
    price: {
      oldUan: '4 333 грн',
      newUan: '3 799 грн'
    },
    name: 'Motorola MOTO G4 (XT1622) Black'
  }, {
    ratingReviews: '1355 отзывов',
    price: '4 999 грн',
    name: 'Samsung Galaxy J7 J700H/DS Black + карта памяти 16гб + чехол + защитное стекло!'
  }, {
    ratingReviews: '426 отзывов',
    price: '5 199 грн',
    name: 'Samsung Galaxy J5 (2016) J510H/DS Black + защитное стекло + чехол!'
  }, {
    ratingReviews: '403 отзыва',
    price: '4 349 грн',
    name: 'Xiaomi Redmi Note 4X 3/32GB Black'
  }, {
    ratingReviews: '488 отзывов',
    price: '6 199 грн',
    name: 'Samsung Galaxy J7 (2016) J710F/DS Gold + защитное стекло + чехол!'
  }, {
    ratingReviews: '198 отзывов',
    price: {
      oldUan: '3 495 грн',
      newUan: '2 995 грн'
    },
    name: 'Lenovo K5 (A6020a40) Silver'
  }, {
    ratingReviews: '352 отзыва',
    price: {
      oldUan: '9 799 грн',
      newUan: '7 999 грн'
    },
    name: 'Apple iPhone 5s 16GB Space Gray'
  }, {
    ratingReviews: '59 отзывов',
    price: '6 000 грн',
    name: 'Nokia 5 Dual Sim Tempered Blue'
  }, {
    ratingReviews: '119 отзывов',
    price: '11 999 грн',
    name: 'Samsung Galaxy A5 2017 Duos SM-A520 Black + карта памяти 128гб!'
  }, {
    ratingReviews: '1106 отзывов',
    price: '3 999 грн',
    name: 'Samsung Galaxy J5 J500H/DS Black + чехол + защитное стекло!'
  }, {
    ratingReviews: '380 отзывов',
    price: '2 199 грн',
    name: 'Huawei Y3 II Tiffany (White-Blue) + чехол + защитное стекло!'
  }, {
    ratingReviews: '86 отзывов',
    price: {
      oldUan: '24 999 грн',
      newUan: '22 999 грн'
    },
    name: 'Samsung Galaxy S8 64GB Midnight Black + карта памяти 64гб + оригинальный чехол!'
  }, {
    ratingReviews: '177 отзывов',
    price: '6 499 грн',
    name: 'Huawei P8 Lite 2017 White + УМБ Huawei AP08Q + защитное стекло + чехол!'
  }, {
    ratingReviews: '347 отзывов',
    price: '4 299 грн',
    name: 'Xiaomi Redmi 4X 3/32GB Black (Международная версия)'
  }, {
    ratingReviews: '709 отзывов',
    price: '2 799 грн',
    name: 'Samsung Galaxy J1 2016 SM-J120H Black + защитное стекло + чехол!'
  }, {
    ratingReviews: '527 отзывов',
    price: '3 999 грн',
    name: 'Huawei Y6 Pro Gold + чехол + защитное стекло!'
  }, {
    ratingReviews: '66 отзывов',
    price: '16 499 грн',
    name: 'Apple iPhone 6s 32GB Gold'
  }, {
    ratingReviews: '14 отзывов',
    price: '11 499 грн',
    name: 'Apple iPhone 6 32GB Space Gray'
  }, {
    ratingReviews: '70 отзывов',
    price: {
      oldUan: '7 399 грн',
      newUan: '5 999 грн'
    },
    name: 'Asus ZenFone 2 32GB (ZE551ML) Black'
  }, {
    ratingReviews: '45 отзывов',
    price: '4 299 грн',
    name: 'Nokia 3 Dual Sim Silver White + сертификаты 500 грн!'
  }, {
    ratingReviews: '376 отзывов',
    price: '3 899 грн',
    name: 'Meizu M3 Note 32GB Grey (Международная версия)'
  }, {
    ratingReviews: '111 отзывов',
    price: {
      oldUan: '9 999 грн',
      newUan: '7 999 грн'
    },
    name: 'Sony Xperia X Dual (F5122) White'
  }, {
    ratingReviews: '40 отзывов',
    price: '2 222 грн',
    name: 'Lenovo Vibe C (A2020) Black + УМБ PowerPlant 5200 mAh в подарок!'
  }, {
    ratingReviews: '93 отзыва',
    price: '18 999 грн',
    name: 'Apple iPhone 7 32GB Black'
  }, {
    ratingReviews: '33 отзыва',
    price: '16 999 грн',
    name: 'Huawei P10 4/32GB Black + сертификат 2500грн + чехол Huawei Smart View Cover!'
  }, {
    ratingReviews: '71 отзыв',
    price: {
      oldUan: '2 399 грн',
      newUan: '1 999 грн'
    },
    name: 'LG K5 X220ds Gold'
  }, {
    ratingReviews: '39 отзывов',
    price: '2 995 грн',
    name: 'Lenovo C2 Power (K10a40) Black'
  }, {
    ratingReviews: '156 отзывов',
    price: '2 599 грн',
    name: 'Nous NS 5006 Gold'
  }, {
    ratingReviews: '40 отзывов',
    price: '19 689 грн',
    name: 'LG G6 Mystic White'
  }, {
    ratingReviews: '24 отзыва',
    price: '5 995 грн',
    name: 'Motorola MOTO G5 (XT1676) Grey'
  }, {
    ratingReviews: '7 отзывов',
    price: {
      oldUan: '10 999 грн',
      newUan: '9 999 грн'
    },
    name: 'HTC One X10 Dual Sim Silver'
  }, {
    ratingReviews: '18 отзывов',
    price: {
      oldUan: '5 999 грн',
      newUan: '4 999 грн'
    },
    name: 'Sony Xperia L1 Dual Black'
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const sortedByRating = () => {
    const copy = [...products];
    return copy.sort((a, b) => {
        const [ratingA] = a.ratingReviews.split(' ');
        const [ratingB] = b.ratingReviews.split(' ');
        return ratingB - ratingA;
    });
};

const sortedByPrice = () => {
    const copy = [...products];
    return copy.sort((a, b) => {
        let priceA = a.price.newUan ? a.price.newUan.replace(/\s+/g, '') : a.price.replace(/\s+/g, '');
        priceA = priceA.slice(0, priceA.length - 3);
        let priceB = b.price.newUan ? b.price.newUan.replace(/\s+/g, '') : b.price.replace(/\s+/g, '');
        priceB = priceB.slice(0, priceB.length - 3);
        return priceB - priceA;
    });
};
```

Comment: @crg you missed!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const sortedByPrice = () => products.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.price.newUan && b.price.newUan) return parseFloat(b.price.newUan) - parseFloat(a.price.newUan);
  if (a.price.newUan) return parseFloat(b.price) - parseFloat(a.price.newUan);
  if (b.price.newUan) return parseFloat(b.price.newUan) - parseFloat(a.price);
  return parseFloat(b.price) - parseFloat(a.price);
});
```

We make use of the return statement stopping all following statements.

Comment: The question author was sorting by price incorrectly - global parseFloat [stops at the first character not useful to it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat#description) and the prices include spaces for readability. This answer shows one way to sort by price or newUan, but suffers from the same bug.